# Run fluent-ffmpeg in browser javascript (client side)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

In my program I use fluent-ffmpeg to convert a video into streamable HLS format (m3u8). but this is very cpu heavy and I'm wondering if it could be run at client-side in the browser. In this manner I'll be offloading some work from the server. If so, how to install it to be available in html `<script>` tag? I also tried asking in their github directly but no response so far...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know what you are looking for, take a look at the [ffmpeg.wasm](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm) project, with it you will be able to use `ffmpeg` "on the client side", passing the following code:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg@0.10.0/dist/ffmpeg.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to create a video from Canvas elements as frames completely client side (I have a serverless Vue SPA)?